# argh invalid form authenticity token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

i don't understand i am already sending both the session key and the authenticity token like so:

> started POST
>   "/test_cases/20/upload_script?authenticity_token=IeH8aJgyM1zgW50MXN9UMj1P2wXKO8ir6lvPr1By5ow=&_waftt2_session=BAh7CUkiD3Nlc3Npb25faWQGOgZFRiIlM2M2YTA3M2NjM2VkZDFmYzBiZTA3MTE2NWYwY2E3MTlJIhBfY3NyZl90b2tlbgY7AEZJIjFJZUg4YUpneU0xemdXNTBNWE45VU1qMVAyd1hLTzhpcjZsdlByMUJ5NW93PQY7AEZJIhV1c2VyX2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzBjsARkkiAYA1YjY5NzQ4YjI3NWYzYzJkOTI2NjE3YmI3NzM3ZTQ3NGM2MmFiNjJhY2U2MzI4ZWUwOTcyOWQ2Y2NkNTVlNzViZWI5ZmQzZjkxNGUxYmIzYTQ0MWQ0ODQ3YTVlMDY5YTMyZmFlMDQwMGVmN2NkYjRhZGFkMDgxYmFkOWQxOTJkZQY7AFRJIhh1c2VyX2NyZWRlbnRpYWxzX2lkBjsARmkCSAI=--3833637df52e559ca3bb3eb6d0d6b5a611d82bf4"

and the whole session key is also being set in env['HTTP_COOKIE'] - yes the key and the value

what am i missing here?

Comment: How is this request being generated? Are you setting env['HTTP_COOKIE'] yourself or is it just the current value of the session cookie sent by the browser? I fixed a similar problem in my app but need more context to know if it is the same problem.

Comment: i am setting env['HTTP_COOKIE'] myself, so not from the browser. Is it being generated by swfupload, but its just a normal post request as far as i know - i just append the authenticity token and the session key on the url.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with swfupload.

As far as I can remember:

It happens because Flash doesn't set the cookie correctly in its first request (2nd and subsequent requests are OK). I used some Rack middleware to copy the session key into env['HTTP_COOKIE] but it didn't work as expected.

My invetigations led me to a bug in the Rack::Request object which prevents it from correctly setting cookies if env['HTTP_COOKIE'] is initially empty.

Here is the middleware code that eventually fixed it for me:

```
class FlashUploadMiddleware
  def initialize(app,session_key)
   @app = app
   @session_key = session_key
  end

  def call(env)
    env['HTTP_COOKIE'] = "bugfix=true" unless env['HTTP_COOKIE']
    if env['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] =~ /^(Adobe|Shockwave) Flash/
      req = Rack::Request.new( env )
      req.cookies[ @session_key ] = req["session_id"] unless req["session_id"].nil?
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end

end
```

This class needs to be in a file called flash_upload_middleware.rb somewhere in your load path. It is initialised from an .rb file in config/initialisers

```
ActionController::Dispatcher.middleware.use( 
    FlashUploadMiddleware,
    ActionController::Base.session_options[:key] )
```

Comment: Hi Noel, I have a similar setup actually pulled my code form this site: https://github.com/lardawge/swfupload-rails-authentication but hold on - yours is a little different, you have this: req = Rack::Request.new( env )
      req.cookies[ @session_key ]  but the code i pulled from was using this: env['HTTP_COOKIE']  so if they are any different, yours might work. I will try tomorrow when i report to work. cross fingers.

Comment: Hi David, I originally lifted some code from a blog somewhere that did the same, but I couldn't get it working. I can't recall the process that led me to use the Request object. ps. this code is not identical to my implementation (I hard coded the seesion_key to '_test_session' in several places) so you might need to play with the initialization code which I just quoted verbatim from the original.